# hibernate schema validation, fail on additional columns/tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have hibernate 4.3.10.Final in my project and

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

in my config, but it does not fail validation when database contains additional tables or mapped table contains additional column.

Is it possible to (simply) force hibernate to fail validation/throw exception when database is not exactly what my mapping says it should be?